# Minesweeper Queens

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, minesweeper

<sub>Based off of: [Ken Duisenberg's Puzzle of the Week](http://ken.duisenberg.com/potw/) Oct. 15, 2003: Minesweeper Queens</sub>

For the puzzle, in the given diagram, the numbered squares are empty, from which the given mines can be attacked by a chess queen. As in standard chess, a queen can attack all eight directions, ***and only one mine in a single direction***.

For example:

> Place 5 mines:
>
> |  |  |  |  |  |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 |  |  |  | 2 |
> |  |  |  | 4 |  |
> |  |  |  | 3 |  |

has 4 solutions, one of them being (`x` represents a mine)

> ```
> +---+---+---+---+---+
> | 1 | x | x | x | 2 |
> +---+---+---+---+---+
> |   |   | x | 4 |   |
> +---+---+---+---+---+
> |   |   |   | 3 | x |
> +---+---+---+---+---+
> ```

---

---

---

To get the $\color{green}✓$:

> - Place 13 mines in this grid
> - Show the steps you took.

> ```
> +---+---+---+---+---+---+
> |   | 4 |   | 4 |   |   |
> +---+---+---+---+---+---+
> | 4 |   |   |   |   |   |
> +---+---+---+---+---+---+
> |   |   | 6 |   |   |   |
> +---+---+---+---+---+---+
> | 5 |   |   |   |   |   |
> +---+---+---+---+---+---+
> |   |   |   | 5 |   |   |
> +---+---+---+---+---+---+
> | 3 |   | 4 |   |   |   |
> +---+---+---+---+---+---+
> ```

Comment: Are the lines-of-sight blocked by numbers (as if there was a friendly queen standing on each numbered space), or only by mines?

Comment: @TimC Only by mines is my understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two numbers in the grid are forcing 3 mines:

> [image]

From this point, I feel like there are many possible paths, just by trying to satisfy each number with the closest mines that don't contradict any other already cleared number. Here's a possible next step with 10 mines:

> [image]

Now, 5 spots on the right are not seen by any number. Just pick your favourite 3 and place mines in them to reach the required number of 13 mines.

> [image]